# Linq To Xml Null Checking of attributes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<books>
   <book name="Christmas Cheer" price="10" />
   <book name="Holiday Season" price="12" />
   <book name="Eggnog Fun" price="5" special="Half Off" />
</books>
```

I'd like to parse this using linq and I'm curious what methods other people use to handle special. My current way of working with this is:

```
var books = from book in booksXml.Descendants("book")
                        let Name = book.Attribute("name") ?? new XAttribute("name", string.Empty)
                        let Price = book.Attribute("price") ?? new XAttribute("price", 0)
                        let Special = book.Attribute("special") ?? new XAttribute("special", string.Empty)
                        select new
                                   {
                                       Name = Name.Value,
                                       Price = Convert.ToInt32(Price.Value),
                                       Special = Special.Value
                                   };
```

I am wondering if there are better ways to solve this.

Thanks,

- Jared

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast the attribute to a `string`. If it is absent you will get `null` and subsequent code should check for `null`, otherwise it will return the value directly.

Try this instead:

```
var books = from book in booksXml.Descendants("book")
            select new
            {
                Name = (string)book.Attribute("name"),
                Price = (string)book.Attribute("price"),
                Special = (string)book.Attribute("special")
            };
```

Comment: That's awesome! I love it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about using an extension method to encapsulate the missing attribute cases:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static T AttributeValueOrDefault<T>(this XElement element, string attributeName, T defaultValue)
    {
        var attribute = element.Attribute(attributeName);
        if (attribute != null && attribute.Value != null)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(attribute.Value, typeof(T));
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work if `T` is a type to which string knows to convert via IConvertible.  If you wanted to support more general conversion cases, you may need to look for a TypeConverter, as well.  This will throw an exception if the type fails to convert.  If you want those cases to return the default as well, you'll need to perform additional error handling.

Comment: I used a variant on this one, but used `XAttribute Attribute<T>(this XElement element, XName name, T defaultValue)`. If it fails, create a `new XAttribute(name,defaultValue);`. Then the overload is there alongside the original one

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6.0 you can use monadic Null-conditional operator `?.` 
After applying it in your example it would look like this:

```
var books = from book in booksXml.Descendants("book")
            select new
            {
                Name = book.Attribute("name")?.Value ?? String.Empty,
                Price = Convert.ToInt32(book.Attribute("price")?.Value ?? "0"),
                Special = book.Attribute("special")?.Value ?? String.Empty
            };
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) in part titled Null-conditional operators.