# Handling null XElements whilst parsing an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, error-handling, linq-to-xml

Is there a better way of doing something like this:

```
private XElement GetSafeElem(XElement elem, string key)
{
    XElement safeElem = elem.Element(key);
    return safeElem ?? new XElement(key);
}

private string GetAttributeValue(XAttribute attrib)
{
    return attrib == null ? "N/A" : attrib.Value;
}

var elem = GetSafeElem(elem, "hdhdhddh");
string foo = GetAttributeValue(e.Attribute("fkfkf"));

//attribute now has a fallback value
```

When parsing elements/attribute values from an XML document? In some cases the element may not be found when doing something like:

```
string foo (string)elem.Element("fooelement").Attribute("fooattribute").Value
```

So an object reference error would occur (assuming the element/attribute aren't found). Same when trying to access the element value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15837829/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4336837/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/792919/11683

Comment: I know that doesn't anwser the question, but you may be interested by a technology named XPATH which handles this kind of problem very gracefully (although it has its own problem too)

Comment: Alternatively you can create a VB.NET project in your solution solely to host the code that parses XML. In VB, you can write `foo = elem.<fooelement1>.<fooelement2>.<fooelement3>.@fooattribute`, and it will return an empty string if any of the nodes in the chain is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is a better approach, but i saw it in a CodeProject post and thought it might be a useful approach here.

Its a monadic solution using a "With" extension method:

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
       Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
       where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o);
}
```

and a Return extension method:

```
public static TResult Return<TInput,TResult>(this TInput o, 
       Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue) where TInput: class
{
  if (o == null) return failureValue;
  return evaluator(o);
}
```

And combining them both together your query could look like this:

```
var myElement = element.With(x => x.Element("FooElement")).Return(x => x.Attribute("FooAttribute").Value, "MyDefaultValue")
```

Not sure its prettier than using the simple extension methods the guys already suggested in previous posts, but its a bit more generic and is a nice approach IMO

[CodeProject - Chained null checks and the Maybe monad](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad)

Comment: I think this is the best approach since it allows me to pass in a default value rather than returning an new `XElement`. It's also useful in that it can be used with any type and not just `XElement`.

Answer (score 5):

I would just use extension methods. It's the same thing, but it's prettier:

```
public static XElement SafeElement(this XElement element, XName name)
{
    return element.Element(name) ?? new XElement(name);
}

public static XAttribute SafeAttribute(this XElement element, XName name)
{
    return element.Attribute(name) ?? new XAttribute(name, string.Empty);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
string foo = element.SafeElement("fooelement").SafeAttribute("fooattribute").Value;
```

Comment: I would also add check for null for element. And in case the goal to not fail in any situation, I would replace XName type to string and check for IsNullOrWhiteSpace (but it can lead to unexpected error, which can be hard to handle)

Answer (score 3):

In C# 6.0 you can use monadic Null-conditional operator `?.` 
After applying it in your example it would look like this:

```
string foo = elem.Element("fooelement")?.Attribute("fooattribute")?.Value;
```

If fooelement or fooattribute does not exist whole expression would result in null. You can read more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) in part titled Null-conditional operators.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way;

```
public static string TryGetElementValue(this XElement parentEl, string elementName, string defaultValue = null) 
{
    var foundEl = parentEl.Element(elementName);
    if(foundEl != null)
    {
     return foundEl.Value;
    }
else
{
     return defaultValue;
}
}
```

and then change code like this:

```
select new News()
                {
                    id = noticia.TryGetElementValue("IdNoticia"),
                    published = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Data"),
                    title = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Titol"),
                    subtitle = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Subtitol"),
                    thumbnail = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Thumbnail", "http://server/images/empty.png")
                };
```